# How to limit the docker container memory usage

Tags: docker

I have a vm flexible to change CPU and Memory on it. I have 5 containers running on it.The 3 three slave containers execute test cases.But when I run the containers,I see that the entire CPU is being filled.Even I increase the size of CPU ,it is also being filled.How do I overcome it.
Limiting the size of each container is the only option??

Comment: There's a whole swath of [docker run options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources)  and equivalent [Docker Compose settings](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources).

Answer (score 2):

You can [limit a container's resources](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) (memory and [CPU](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu)) **at run-time**. For example :

```
docker run --cpus=".5" my-container
```

to allow only 50% of a CPU for `my-container`.

Those settings are [run-time settings](https://forums.docker.com/t/memory-and-cpu-limit-in-dockerfile/198/2), so you cannot set them in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Thanx for the answer but I want to l imit in dockerfile itself not during run time.Sorry that I didnot ask that earlier

Comment: You can't, those are run-time settings : see my updated answer. Please also update your question according to your needs (set those settings in `Dockerfile`) to help other people with the same question find answers.

Comment: @Sunil that's not how containers are supposed to work. If you're looking to throttle process CPU usage of the process running in the container you would have to use some utilitities (maybe like [cpulimit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cpulimit.1.html)), but there are no such settings in Dockerfile directives.